# Is it possible to get the open incident count from newrelic alerts

Tags: json, bash, curl, newrelic

We are trying to get the open incident count from newrelic alert section using `curl` with API (Jason format). This must exclude Acknowledged incidents. When we try with "`alerts_incidents.json`" as below with `curl`, it's generating the output with all open and closed incidents and not mention anything about the acknowledged incidents

```
curl -H 'X-Api-Key:{}' -i -X GET ' HTTP/1.1 200 OKrelic.com/v2/alerts_incidents.json'
```

Please see the attached screenshot. We need the count of the alerts as mentioned in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: We got all open alerts from newrelic using the below CURL command. We need to filter the acknowledged alerts from this open alerts to get our exact output


curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_incidents.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:{api_key}' -i \
     -G -d 'only_open=true'

Comment: I got the fix, hence resolving this thread.